# How close to GPU theoretical memory bandwidth can you get?

Tags: memory, optimization, gpu, bandwidth

Suppose you have a memory bound GPU kernel, how close can you get to the stated theoretical bandwidth of the GPU? Even in [Mark Harris's Optimising Parallel Reduction presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) he 'only' gets 63GB/sec which is about 73% of the bandwidth of his test GPU (a G80) which he claimed 84.6GB/sec peak bandwidth. Could Harris have optimised his kernel further? are there other techniques which which were possibly to advanced/out of scope for the presentation? eg __shfl type instructions?  Why didn't he achieve a higher bandwidth?

[This](http://web.stanford.edu/~mebauer/pdfs/cudadma-sc11.pdf) article claims, using a test machine with a Tesla C2050

> "throughput is memory-bandwidth limited, sustaining around 75% of the
>   144 GB/s peak memory bandwidth, compared to a practical limit of 85%
>   of peak when accounting for overheads such as DRAM refresh."

Is this correct? The authors don't provide a source for the "85% practical bandwidth limit" and I haven't been able to find anything else mentioning it. If so, what other factors (supposing you have a very well optimised kernel) would prevent you from reaching theoretical peak bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

A similar thread: [GPU Memory bandwidth theoretical vs practical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720791/gpu-memory-bandwidth-theoretical-vs-practical)

Running a minimal kernel that only writes data to a 1D large vector:

```
__global__ void kernel( int *out ) {
    int idx =  threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    out[idx] = idx%4;
}
```

on GeForce GT 710 I got 0.9 of the theoretical bandwidth

> practical 12.9 GB/s.
>
> theoretical (spec) 14.4 GB/s

One thing that might contribute to the slow down is the caching.